# Bokeh: allow legend to be larger then plot_width

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I am trying to create a gridplot using bokeh.

My future goal is that both plots share the same legend, which I was already able to do. But my problem is, that the legend which is connected to a plot, is hidden when the width of the legend is wider than the `plot_width`. The picture below shows my problem very well.

[image: The legend is hidden]

```
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.layouts import row, column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Legend
output_notebook()

df = pd.DataFrame({'blue':[3,4,3,2,2,42,1,3,3,9][::-1], 
                   'red':[3,4,3,2,2,42,1,3,3,9], 
                   'green':[42,1,3,3,9,3,4,3,2,2], 
                   'black':[42,1,3,3,9,3,4,3,2,2][::-1]
                  }, 
                  index=pd.RangeIndex(start=1, stop=11, name='index'))
source = ColumnDataSource(df)
p1 = figure(plot_width=500, 
            plot_height=500,
           )
p1.add_layout(Legend(visible=False))
p2 = figure(plot_width=270, 
            plot_height=500,
           )
p2.add_layout(Legend(click_policy="hide", orientation='horizontal', spacing=20, visible=True, margin=1), 'below')
for name in df.columns:
    p1.line(x='index', y=name, source=source, color=name, legend_label=name)
    p2.line(x='index', y=name, source=source, color=name, legend_label=name)    
    
show(row(p1,p2))
```

I have also tried to add an invisible third plot below the `row` with the the sum of the width of both sub figures in the hope that I can show only the legend. The closest I can get is this:

[image: Dirty Hack]

```
p1 = figure(plot_width=500, 
            plot_height=500,
           )
p1.add_layout(Legend(visible=False))
p2 = figure(plot_width=270, 
            plot_height=500,
           )
p2.add_layout(Legend(click_policy="hide", orientation='horizontal', spacing=20, visible=False, margin=1), 'below')
   
p3 = figure(plot_width=770, 
            plot_height=47,
           )
p3.xaxis.visible=False
p3.yaxis.visible=False
p3.add_layout(Legend(click_policy="hide", orientation='horizontal', spacing=20, visible=True, margin=1), 'below')
for name in df.columns:
    p1.line(x='index', y=name, source=source, color=name, legend_label=name)
    p2.line(x='index', y=name, source=source, color=name, legend_label=name)
    p3.line(x='index', y=name, source=source, color=name, legend_label=name)    
    
show(column(row(p1,p2), p3))
```

Is there a cleaner solution for this problem?

Comment: you can simple add the legend to the plot on the left that has the largest width. Another solution in my view is to create a third plot with an empty canvas and add the legend to it.